# getting an error of " an integer is required (got type DeferredAttribute)"

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, unix-timestamp

i need to group data based on hour extracted from a 13 digit unix timestamp.those timestamps are stored in a model(Hello) field called startTime with IntegerField

```
timehour = Hello.objects.values(
    #hour=ExtractHour('startTime')
    hour=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp((Hello.startTime)).strftime('%H')
).annotate(
    times=Count('pk')
).order_by('hour')
```

my model looks like this

```
class Hello(models.Model):
   startTime=models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

Comment: You're doing something completely wrong. `values` method used to get only certain fields, but not for annotation. The error is caused by the fact that you're trying to get field value from model in improper way - `Hello.startTime`

Comment: can u suggest another way of doing the thing i am doing as mention in first two lines

Comment: Please show your models first.

Comment: class Hello(models.Model):
   
    startTime = models.IntegerField( blank=True, null=True)

Comment: `InteractionWith` as well. Also, you can update your question instead of posting models code in comments.